# Regex: select name and surname

Tags: php, regex

I want to select just the names of persons in the 3 examples and exclude this part: `Nom :   Mr` or `Nom :   Mme`:

```
Nom :   Mr Name Surname
Nom :   Mr Name1 Name2 Surname
Nom :   Mme Name Surname
Nom :   Mme Name1 Name2 Surname
```

I'm using Regex with a generator : http://gskinner.com/RegExr/
I will use it with PHP 
I tried

```
(?<=Nom :)(.*)
```

but it gives nothing as it includes Mr or Mme that I want to exclude
any help please?

Comment: What is your target language? Otherwise you will get regex patterns which wont work on your system.

Comment: Hello OmegaMan
I will use it with PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
Nom\s+:\s+M(?:r|me)\s+(.*)
```

or you could do..

```
(?<=Nom :)\s+M(?:r|me)\s+(.*)
```

or make it even shorter

```
M(?:r|me)\s+(.*)$
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches the target input:

```
((?<=Nom :   Mr )|(?<=Nom :   Mme )).*$
```

See a [live demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/k9HySSUCo4) working with your examples.

The main difference with this regex over the other answer is that the *entire* match (not just group 1 or whatever) is your target input.

Comment: I use an iPhone which can't open that link (regexr uses flash). Can you post it on [rubular](http://www.rubular.com) please?